# How do I display the size (dimensions) of the image next to it on a webpage

Tags: html, jquery

I was wondering if I can display the dimensions of an image I am putting on my website. For example, I have put 300x400, 500x600, 300x700, etc. images on a webpage.

I have tried this simple JQuery script inside my head tag:

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (onload) {
var el = document.getElementById("#imgdim");
var txt = + $("#imgdim").naturalWidth() + "x" + + 
$("#imgdim").naturalHeight();
console.log({
"naturalWidth": el.naturalWidth,
"naturalHeight": el.naturalHeight,
});
})
</script>
```

Here is my div whose dimensions I want to show to my users:

```html
<img id="imgdim" src="getimg.php?id='.$irow["id"].'"></div>
```

The code should write the height and width of the image loaded with the imgdim ID, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I googled this and didn't find anything related. Thought I would ask where people know the answer to it. Why close the question? I have followed the instructions in "How to Ask"? Thanks @DarkBee

Comment: I didn't ask anyone to write me code. My question is "Is there a known way to do this?" and I don't believe I am begging for coding from others here. I really can't believe such a platform would just ban each and every question I post here.

Comment: Consider splitting up the problem you are having and looking for the steps separately. You will need to figure out how to get the dimensions of the image and you'll need to figure out how to create and insert a dynamic element into your `HTML`  with said dimensions as the content/text of the created element. That being said, this can't be solved with `HTML` alone

Comment: YES, I don't know how that would work and I consequently CANNOT break it down into steps and that's why I have asked the question here. People are more than generous here and you are not letting me get help.

Comment: [Getting an image's dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+image+dimensions) - [appending a div](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+append+div)

Comment: That's not a `div`, that's an `img`. A variable, `txt` is created with (apparently) the text you want in the `div`, but it's not appended to the `div` (wherever that is). Where do you think the "code should write the height and width of the image"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the image size (height & width) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-the-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with my code. Let's go through them one by one:

1. Incorrect selector in getElementById: We don't need to include the # symbol when passing the ID to getElementById. We will update this line:

   `var el = document.getElementById("imgdim");`
2. jQuery syntax errors: I was using incorrect syntax when trying to access the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties of the image using jQuery. Instead of `$("#imgdim").naturalWidth()`, it should be `$("#imgdim")[0].naturalWidth` to access the native DOM element. The same applies to `naturalHeight`.
3. `console.log` statement: The console.log statement is not necessary for displaying the dimensions to users. We can update the text content of an HTML element to show the dimensions instead.

Here's the modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var el = document.getElementById("imgdim");
        var txt = el.naturalWidth + "x" + el.naturalHeight;
        var dimensionsElement = document.getElementById("dimensions");
        dimensionsElement.textContent = txt;
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="imgdim" src="getimg.php?id=<?php echo $irow['id']; ?>">
<div id="dimensions"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code, the dimensions of the image loaded with the ID `imgdim` will be displayed in the  element with the ID `dimensions`. We have to make sure to include the jQuery library before using it in our code.